# jdbc programming through oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

what is the service name of oracle10g xe database

Comment: Please choose tags carefully. `JavaScript` != `Java` and `.NET` != `Java`. I removed the irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 1):

It varies ragarding the network. In our local system it'll be `'localhost'`

Comment: ... `localhost` is the IP (127.0.0.1) if you have a local install of the oracle database. The service name is a different part of the connect string.

Answer (score 1):

The jdbc url for a locally installed xe databse would look like this: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE`, note that `XE` is the SID, a service name does not seem to be needed for jdbc.

Comment: You can assign different services to the same SID (eg for resource management purposes) using listener.ora. But by default you'll get a service with the same name as the sid, which is XE.

Answer (score 0):

Service name is ambigious. But as you asked about jdbc I guess you need advice on the service name that is used on the jdbc url.

Here is a [good article](http://www.jetbrains.net/jira/browse/SQLQ-19) with a link to oracle sources.

Basically it says that the format is

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:scott/tiger@//myhost:1521/myservicename
```

and `myservicename` can be found in `TNSNAMES.ORA`.